# How to obtain mousewheel information and mouse position together in jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, mousewheel, mouse-position

I am using JQuery mousewheel downloaded from https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/downloads to obtain mousewheel information. At the same, I want to obtain the position of the mouse when the wheel was rolled. How can I achieve this ?

My current function is as below:

```
$(function() {
    $('#maindiv').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {   
    // somehow obtain mouse position
        // Use delta and mouse position for a purpose
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to access the jQuery default behaviour of any event, that allows you to read the `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`.

```
$(function() {
    $('#maindiv').mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {   
        var mousePosition = { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY };
        // ...
    });
});
```

Take a look at the [jQuery-Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) for Details.